# Scanning directories and getting all files in PHP

Tags: php, scandir

My problem is, that I've got 4 directories:

```
/dir1/
/dir2/
/dir3/
/dir4/
```

which may contain any number of subdirectories, for example:

```
    /dir1/
       /subdir1/
       /subdir2/

    /dir2/
       /subdir1/
       /subdir2/
       /subdir3/

    /dir3/
       /subdir1/

    /dir4/
       /subdir1/
       /subdir2/
       /subdir3/
```

These subdirectories, may contain any number of .txt files, for example:

```
/dir1/
   /subdir1/
      /1.txt
      /2.txt
   /subdir2/
      /1.txt

    /dir2/
       /subdir1/
          /1.txt
       /subdir2/
          /1.txt
          /2.txt
       /subdir3/
          /1.txt

    /dir3/
       /subdir1/
          /1.txt
          /2.txt

    /dir4/
       /subdir1/
          /1.txt
       /subdir2/
          /1.txt
       /subdir3/
          /1.txt
          /2.txt
          /3.txt
```

The problem is to find these .txt files in an automated way.

**Impartant:** There are only 2 levels of directories, as it's shown above.
I've managed to get so far:

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/public/dir1/.
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/public/dir1/..
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/public/dir1/subdir1/1.txt
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/public/dir1/subdir1/1.txt
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/public/dir1/subdir2/1.txt
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/public/dir1/subdir2/1.txt
```

With:

```
$path = realpath('/dir1');
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path)) as $filename) {
                $files[] = $filename;
            }

for ($i=0; $i < count($files); $i++) {
    echo $files[$i] . "<br>";
}
```

An array of paths, such as `array(sub1/1.txt, sub1/2.txt, sub2/1.txt ...)` would also be appreciated.
Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using RecursiveDirectoryIterator, you should take a look at [globiterator](http://php.net/manual/en/globiterator.construct.php) which helps you traversing directory and matching files.

**EDIT**: 
As stated in the documentation :

> Iterates through a file system in a similar fashion to glob().

You can easily loop through the files matching a pattern :

```
$it = new GlobIterator('./*/*.txt');
foreach($it as $item){
    var_dump($item->getFilename());
}
```

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/305455) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @jmattheis Duly noted. I added a quote from the link and an example relevant to the question. Thanks for your remarks and for the links, they were interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

**UPDATE**

```
<?php

function scanDirectory($directory) {

    $files = glob($directory . '/*');

    $data = array();
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if (is_dir($file)) {
            $data = array_merge($data, scanDirectory($file));
        } else if (substr($file,-4) == '.txt') {
            $data[] = $file;
        }
    }

    return $data;
}

$startDirectory = realpath(__DIR__);

$data = scanDirectory($startDirectory);

var_dump($data);

?>
```

Comment: Or even is it possible to get a nice array of paths? Such as array("sub1/1.txt", "sub2/1.txt" ... ) ?